# An operation was attemped on something that is not a socket in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

In my program I want a socket to connect to a server without blocking the main thread, so I launch another thread to run over my `connect_to_server(ip, port)` function.

The first connection goes smoothly and upon exit the thread safely exits the function and ends his role.

However when trying to launch the thread for the second time I get an error.

I honestly had no idea where or how I should go about fixing this problem, because as far as I know the `client` socket doesn't change anywhere in this function and can not be changed from outside because he is in a function.

```py
def connect_to_server(ip, port):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((ip, port))

    data = _receive(client).decode()
    if data == "valid":
        print("Maintaining connection with server.")
        _send(client, "OK".encode())

        # Starting thread to to recv data simultaneously
        start_new_thread(receive_data, (client, ))

        # Connecting to the game server until disconnection.
        while True:
                # Data sending if there is data to send in input queue
                data = to_server_queue.get(True)
                print("Data sent to server", data)
                _send(client, data)
                if some_condition_to_break:
                    break
    client.close()

def receive_data(client):
    while True:
        data = _receive(client)
        output_queue.put(data)
        if some_condition_to_break:
            break


def _send(conn, data):
    """
    Sends the data. First sends length of incoming data, then the data itself.
    :param conn: The 'other side' of the connection.
    :param data: Data to be sent in bytes.
    :return:
    """
    try:
        length = len(data)
        length_to_send = ''
        for x in range(len(str(length)), 6):
            length_to_send += '0'
        length_to_send += str(length)

        conn.send(length_to_send.encode())
        conn.send(data)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


def _receive(conn):
    """
    Receives data. First receives the length, then the data itself.
    :param conn: The 'other side' of the connection.
    :return: Returns the received data in bytes.
    """
    try:
        raw_data = conn.recv(6).decode()
        length = int(raw_data)
        raw_data = conn.recv(length)
        return raw_data
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

This is the error I get, although I expect it to behave like the first thread.

```py
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function connect_to_server at 0x0382BA08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\----\Core.py", line 34, in _send
    conn.send(length_to_send.encode())
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\----\Core.py", line 37, in _send
    raise e
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Where do you _join_ the thread you created? I'm wondering if your first thread is not fully out of the picture when you're starting up the new one. For example, how do you know your old thread is not still in the `receive_data` loop? Maybe it's still blocked in a `recv` call? (Or was, until the socket got closed out from under it.) In any case, there's nothing (in the code you've presented here at least) indicating that you'd actually know if the thread had ended. It would help if you present a [mcve]

Comment: I have actually solved the problem just now. My problem was that the condition to break out of the send and receive loop only updated in the receive loop. Leaving the socket in the send function in an infinite while True loop. Thus when creating a new thread and running him, it would cause my error. Also I'm still wondering why that happens because a new socket instance is created anyhow as far as I know... By the way, if I would join the thread it would block my main program, and won't allow me to receive and send data simultaneously. Thanks for taking your time to help :)

Comment: Joining the sub-thread won't block your main thread (for any appreciable length of time) if both threads are aware of the condition. If sharing the socket between a sender and a receiver, they can signal each other _through the socket_ by using the `shutdown` method (*prior* to closing the socket). If the receiver decides to quit, do a `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` on the socket, and the sender will find out on the next `send` attempt. Likewise, the sender can use `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` to cause the receiver to get an EOF. Join sub-thread _then_ close. Lockstep synchronization is usually the best practice.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! I'll definitely do that and continue practicing this. How ever, I still have 1 remaining question. Every time I create a thread to run over that function, a new instance of a `socket` object should be created, with out any relativity to other `socket` instances of other threads running over the same function. So how come that a socket in one thread (blocked) \ (messed up) a socket created by another thread? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. My guess is that the socket file descriptor (which is the operating system object actually linking you to the network peer, which underlies the python socket object) got closed in one thread while the other thread was still using it. That would explain the exception you got. I don't immediately see how that maps to your code.